# Как в 'личном кабинет -> заказы' из всех заказов которые есть, доставать и показывать только нужную позицию и выводить ее вместе с картинкой

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть заказы, все заказы подразделены на категории. В категории "Все товары" и "Одежда" будет стандартный вывод заказов (как на картинке), но вот "Курсы", "Консультация" и т.д будет просто видна картинка, название и время через которое пропадет этот заказ (Заказы кроме Одежды будут исчезать после определенного времени). Вот что-то типо такого должно быть в этих разделах: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Насколько я понимаю, должен приходить заказ, из этого заказа я узнаю что был куплен определенный (например) курс и только этот курс должен появиться во вкладке "курсы". Но как доставать определенный пункт из заказа? Я разбил все на категории, но если в заказе есть одежда и курс, то во вкладку "курс" перейдет весь заказ, а не только курс

Подскажите как это можно сделать, может плагин какой, может просто мысли какие-то, может какие-то готовые решения, всему буду очень благодарен

Comment: А то, что у тебя на первой картинке - это какой-то готовый плагин(какой? ссылку плз.) или что-то самописное?

Comment: Это стандартный личный кабинет от woocommerce, а там я уже сам добавил вкладки и с помощью кода проверяю категории и туда вывожу по вкладкам

Comment: В стандартном нет вкладок по категориям, поэтому и возник вопрос. Теперь понятно. Но в таком случае нет разделения на категории. Надо переписывать "механизм вкладок", тогда наверняка возможно сделать то, что ты хочешь.

Comment: Я подумал как вообще можно сделать и мне пришла мысль, что это все выводится в "Деталях заказа", и вот если бы можно было как-то детали заказа занести в сами заказы, то было бы уже проще (но я не знаю как это сделать). И нужно как-то проверять (всего у меня 12 товаров, которые не по одежде и они не будут добавляться), поэтому нужно как-то каждый заказ проверять и если в заказе есть эта позиция (может можно как-то по id) то выводить туда (но я тоже не знаю как это сделать)

Comment: Можно сделать для всех категорий одинаковый вывод (но с кандачка не подскажу - надо маны полистать). Но чтобы для разных категорияй сделать разный вывод - тут уже надо много чего переделывать.